# How to factor a polynomial expression with variable coefficients (and imaginary values)

Tags: complex, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

How can I factor terms with variable coefficients?

For example for the expression: $x^2 + a$

I know that I can factor this to:  $(x+i\sqrt{a})(x -i\sqrt{a})$

How do I do this in mathematica?

I would've expected something like Factor[x^2 + a, x]  but I don't see anything like this so far.

Comment: `Times @@ (x - (x /. Solve[x^2 + a == 0, x]))`

Comment: Thanks Bob!  Here's the function version of your answer which also seems to work: factorVariable[expression_, var_] :=
  Times @@ (var - (var /. Solve[expression == 0, var]));

Comment: If you write that as an answer I'll accept it (which I think will be helpful for people like me who were googling for it and might not see it in the comments)

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: Okay. I thought it might be a bit rude to do this without asking, but I'll go ahead and do that, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For my specific answer, @Bob Hanlon answered that it can be done doing:

```
Times @@ (x - (x /. Solve[x^2 + a == 0, x]))
```

Writing this up in a more general form as a function:

```
factorVariable[expression_, var_] :=
  Times @@ (var - (var /. Solve[expression == 0, var]));
```

This appears to work very well!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are no general way to do this.

```
Factor[x^2 + 1, Extension -> {1, I}]
Factor[x^2 + 2, Extension -> {Sqrt[2], I}]
Factor[x^2 + 3, Extension -> {Sqrt[3], I}]
Factor[x^2 - 1]
Factor[x^2 - 2, Extension -> Sqrt[2]]
Factor[x^4 - 9, Extension -> {Sqrt[3], I}]
Factor[x^4 + 1, Extension -> I]
Factor[x^5 + 1, Extension -> I]
```

```
(-I + x) (I + x)
(Sqrt[2] - I x) (Sqrt[2] + I x)
(Sqrt[3] - I x) (Sqrt[3] + I x)
(-1 + x) (1 + x)
-((Sqrt[2] - x) (Sqrt[2] + x))
-((Sqrt[3] - x) (Sqrt[3] - I x) (Sqrt[3] + I x) (Sqrt[3] + x))
(-I + x^2) (I + x^2)
(1 + x) (1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4)
```